# Centering table and submit button CSS

Tags: html, css, submit

Centering table on my screen works with such CSS lines:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

However for submit button it doesn't work, do i need to enter it manually like `margin-right:400px`? But if other's people screen has bigger resolution then it won't be in center?

Comment: you must specify button width and height?

Comment: hey i have a question that button comes within tr rite? or outside of the table

Comment: I hope this may help you thanks fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/3LZYJ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of text-align property for align it center

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the `text-align` should be applied to the parent element, not the button itself.

Comment: @derekerdmann - yes it require to applied to parent element only not button because its not going to work for the button and there is no direct way to do it

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the button with

```
<center> </center>
```

Comment: `center` is deprecated in HTML 4.01 and doesn't exist in HTML 5. Stay as far away from it as you can.

Comment: Oops. This project is the first time I've really made heavy use of HTML in about 7 years, so I'm a bit rusty...